# Node.js - Rename Function throwing error, oldpath not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make a file upload work using node.js and the formidable package, however when using the fs "rename" function to change the location of the file, it is throwing an error, it looks like the file is undefined for some reason, and I'm not sure why.

The code:

```
        form.parse(request, (err, address, files) => {
            console.log(address);
            console.log(files);
            console.log(files.upload);
            console.log(files.upload.filepath);
            if(files.upload)
            {
                rename(files.upload.filepath, `public/assets/${files.upload.name}`, () => {
                    address['file'] = `/assets/${files.upload.name}`;
                });
            }
            data.addresses = saveAddress(data.addresses, address);
            redirect(response, '/');
        });
    }
```

The output from the console.log()'s :

```
{
  id: [ 'undefined' ],
  firstName: [ 'a' ],
  lastName: [ 'a' ],
  street: [ 'a' ],
  city: [ 'a' ],
  country: [ 'a' ]
}
{
  upload: [
    PersistentFile {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      lastModifiedDate: 2023-08-13T08:11:18.230Z,
      filepath: 'C:\\Users\\mmerc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\4ca3312ae3959becd8765b200',
      newFilename: '4ca3312ae3959becd8765b200',
      originalFilename: 'download.jpg',
      mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
      hashAlgorithm: false,
      size: 7291,
      _writeStream: [WriteStream],
      hash: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  ]
}
[
  PersistentFile {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { error: [Function (anonymous)] },
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    lastModifiedDate: 2023-08-13T08:11:18.230Z,
    filepath: 'C:\\Users\\mmerc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\4ca3312ae3959becd8765b200',
    newFilename: '4ca3312ae3959becd8765b200',
    originalFilename: 'download.jpg',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    hashAlgorithm: false,
    size: 7291,
    _writeStream: WriteStream {
      fd: 3,
      path: 'C:\\Users\\mmerc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\4ca3312ae3959becd8765b200',
      flags: 'w',
      mode: 438,
      start: undefined,
      pos: undefined,
      bytesWritten: 7291,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      [Symbol(kFs)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kIsPerformingIO)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    hash: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  }
]
undefined
```

It looks from the logs that the filepath is defined, but files.upload.filepath outputs as "undefined".

The error in the console I get:

```
node:internal/fs/utils:676
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(propName, ['string', 'Buffer', 'URL'], path);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "oldPath" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined
    at rename (node:fs:1016:13)
    at file:///C:/Users/mmerc/OneDrive/Programming/Web%20Dev/Node%20JS%20Comprehensive/5/index.js:48:17
    at zalgoSafe (C:\Users\mmerc\OneDrive\Programming\Web Dev\Node JS Comprehensive\5\node_modules\dezalgo\dezalgo.js:20:10)
    at f (C:\Users\mmerc\OneDrive\Programming\Web Dev\Node JS Comprehensive\5\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at IncomingForm.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/mmerc/OneDrive/Programming/Web%20Dev/Node%20JS%20Comprehensive/5/node_modules/formidable/src/Formidable.js:228:7)
    at IncomingForm.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at IncomingForm._maybeEnd (file:///C:/Users/mmerc/OneDrive/Programming/Web%20Dev/Node%20JS%20Comprehensive/5/node_modules/formidable/src/Formidable.js:679:10)
    at file:///C:/Users/mmerc/OneDrive/Programming/Web%20Dev/Node%20JS%20Comprehensive/5/node_modules/formidable/src/Formidable.js:438:14
    at Array.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/mmerc/OneDrive/Programming/Web%20Dev/Node%20JS%20Comprehensive/5/node_modules/formidable/src/PersistentFile.js:75:7)
    at finish (node:internal/streams/writable:745:25) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

I'm a bit stumped here, could anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `files.upload` is array, so it should be `files.upload[0].filepath`